# External mergesort inefficiency

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I've implemented an external mergesort to sort a file consisting of Java int primitives, however it is horribly slow (fortunately it does at least work).
Very little happens in the sort method; it just recursively calls merge with blockSize doubling each call and swapping input and output files each time.
Where about could I be losing so much time here?

```
//Merge stage of external mergesort
//Read from input file, already sorted into blocks of size blockSize
//Write to output file, sorted into blocks of 2*blockSize
public static void merge(String inputFile, String outputFile, long blockSize)
    throws IOException
{
  //readers for block1/2
  FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
  DataInputStream dis1 = new DataInputStream(fis1);
  FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
  DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream(fis2);

  //writer to output file
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
  DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

  // merging 2 sub lists
  // go along pairs of blocks in inputFile
  // continue until end of input

  //initialise block2 at right position
  dis2.skipBytes((int) blockSize);

  //while we haven't reached the end of the file
  while (dis1.available() > 0)
    {
      // if block1 is last block, copy block1 to output
      if (dis2.available() <= 0)
        {
          while (dis1.available() > 0) 
            dos.writeInt(dis1.readInt());
          break;
        }
      // if block1 not last block, merge block1 and block2
      else
        {
          long block1Pos = 0;
          long block2Pos = 0;
          boolean block1Over = false;
          boolean block2Over = false;

          //data read from each block
          int e1 = dis1.readInt();
          int e2 = dis2.readInt();

          //keep going until fully examined both blocks
          while (!block1Over | !block2Over)
            {
              //copy from block 1 if:
              //  block1 hasnt been fully examined AND
              //  block1 element less than block2s OR block2 has been fully examined
              while ( !block1Over & ((e1 <= e2) | block2Over) )
                {
                  dos.writeInt(e1); block1Pos += 4;
                  if (block1Pos < blockSize & dis1.available() > 0) 
                    e1 = dis1.readInt();
                  else 
                    block1Over = true;
                }
              //same for block2
              while ( !block2Over & ((e2 < e1) | block1Over) )
                {
                  dos.writeInt(e2); block2Pos += 4;
                  if (block2Pos < blockSize & dis2.available() > 0) 
                    e2 = dis2.readInt();
                  else 
                    block2Over = true;
                }
            }
        }
      // skip to next blocks
      dis1.skipBytes((int) blockSize);
      dis2.skipBytes((int) blockSize);
    }
  dis1.close();
  dis2.close();
  dos.close();
  fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Those streams are not buffered at all, probably the reason for slowness. But I think you should ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, what is the minimum blocksize? If it's too small, you will be creating a huge mess of tiny files for no reason at all...

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: I am starting to wonder if we are splitting SO a bit too much. Keeping track of SO, CR, Programmers, SR and so on is starting to become cumbersome...

Comment: @thkala Yes, the very existence of all these sites is a bad joke. I can't see why this question has been closed. The OP seeks no CR, but asks for a help with a too slow algorithm. I guess your comment solves it, but still...

Comment: @maaartinus: the question was probably closed because the code is incomplete and a lot of contextual information is missing. CR is also supposedly more suitable for performance questions on existing code...

Comment: That said, I feel that questions like this one occasionally result in answers that contain widely helpful guidelines. I am not sure if CR is a good place for such answers - code reviews are generally  specific to the code in question and people doing reviews may not feel the need to explain in general terms. I'm not very familiar with the CR site, however, so I don't know what the overall mentality is like there...

Comment: @thkala I agree. The problem here isn't really the code, although it does have major flaws: it is the choice of algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

1. No buffering. Add BufferedInputStreams and BufferedOutputStreams everywhere.
2. Misuse of available(). It isn't a valid test for end of stream, and it is an extra system call every time you call it. Just wait for the real end of stream indication.
3. Non-optimal initial distribution. The fact that you're receiving a single blocksize indicates that you haven't used replacement-selection distribution, so your initial runs are probably at best half what they could be. This has an exponential effect on the number of merge passes required.
4. Unbalanced merging. You need to add dummy runs to the beginning of the merge phase so that your last merge is N-way, not, in the worst case, two-way. This saves potentially almost an entire extra pass over the data. So you need to know the number of initial runs before you start merging.